# C# operator overloading performance

Tags: c#

I was looking at a C# basic example of operator overloading:

```
public static Vector operator + (Vector lhs, Vector rhs)
{
    Vector result = new Vector(lhs);
    result.x += rhs.x;
    result.y += rhs.y;
    result.z += rhs.z;
    return result;
}
```

And I was wondering, performance-wise would it be the same thing to overload the + operator like this?

```
public static Vector operator + (Vector lhs, Vector rhs)
{
    Vector result = new Vector();
    result.x = rhs.x + lhs.x;
    result.y = rhs.y + lhs.y;
    result.z = rhs.z + lhs.z;
    return result;
}
```

Are there any differences from the first and second example? What's the best solution and why?

Comment: Why are you asking us? Try it, profile it, see if it's good enough for your use case, done.

Comment: I would be very surprised if you could measure any difference at all between `a += b;` and `a = a + b`;

Comment: Don't worry about it now, make it work, make it readable, if later you find it to be the bottleneck in performance, then worry about it. It is a *premature optimization*. *(I believe there wouldn't be any performance difference, even if there is, it would be negligible)*.

Comment: In C#, `+=` cannot be overloaded. `a += b` is just syntax sugar for  `a = a + b`. Therefore, both code blocks compile to the same.

Comment: You, probably, want a `Vector(Double x, Double y, Double z)` constructor and `public static Vector operator + (Vector lhs, Vector rhs) {return new Vector(rhs.x + lhs.x, rhs.y + lhs.y, rhs.z + lhs.z);}` operator

Comment: this isn't really at all related to operator overloading

Comment: @Luaan I couldn't test it since i'm reading a book and I have no way to compile the code right now. It was just a basic question from a beginner to expert developers, the first example was taken from the book and the second it's how I would write the code. It was just a theorical question related to both performance and readability, to know if there were any differences. I could express myself better but I can't understand why so many downvotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second method is actually written incorrectly: you're adding the `.x` property of `rhs` to everything. I'm going to assume that was a simple mistake, and you meant to have the same behavior between the two methods.

These two examples call different constructor overloads, which you haven't included code for. If we can assume that the first example's constructor just sets the `x`, `y`, and `z` properties on that object, then the only difference should be that the first one needs to load the value from the `.x`, `.y`, and `.z` properties before it can set them, so it will have slightly slower performance.

However, this performance difference will be negligible, so unless this is a performance-critical piece of code, you would do better to focus on readability.

Personally, I'd do this:

```
public Vector(int x, int y, int z)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}

public static Vector operator + (Vector lhs, Vector rhs)
{
    return new Vector(
        rhs.x + lhs.x, 
        rhs.y + lhs.y,
        rhs.z + lhs.z;
    );
}
```

Comment: You'd have to check the IL to make sure. I'd bet there won't be any difference.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I don't think I'd need to check the IL to be sure on this one. Assuming the constructor clones all the properties from the given vector, that would need to read the properties once and set the properties once. Then the rest of the code needs to read the properties from that vector as well as `rhs` and set the properties on the result vector again. So that's three reads and two writes for each property. The second example involves two reads and two writes. My suggested code involves two reads and one write.

Comment: The compiler can easily optimize this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: In my experience, the compiler does not try to optimize code beyond the scope of the current function. I can pretty much guarantee you'd get different IL code. The JIT compiler may perform some additional optimizations, but that's difficult to predict. At any rate, my main point remains: unless you can see a measurable difference in performance, it's more important to make your code easy to read than to focus on hyper-optimization.

Answer (score 3):

For semantic readability, example 2.

Any performance difference is negligible, at worst

Comment: why do you consider exemple 1 cleaner? It uses some strange kind of copy constructor, then mutates the struct it obtains by using composite operators when simpler operators would suffice. I don't see the criterion that makes it cleaner for you.

Comment: @Falanwe it is the same operation in less characters. i would prefer to write `result += add` than `result = result + add`. however, i didn't consider the `Vector(lhs)` vs `Vector()` part of the code as i was solely focusing on the expression itself (because it asked what solution is "best"). that said, i have removed that statement ("cleaner code" may have not been what i was trying to portray).

Comment: I don't wanna be snarky, but I think it's very misleading, if not downright ridiculous to measure "clean code" by "how few characters does it have?"

Comment: @kai That's fair. I was only trying to say that it was the same expression in less characters. That's all. That's why I removed that statement (I initially said "overall readability" but even that was suspect). What terminology would you use if "clean code" isn't it?

Comment: @kai Check out points 4 and 7 [here](http://blog.goyello.com/2013/01/21/top-9-principles-clean-code/). That's what I was referring to when I said "clean code."

Comment: you don't measure "smaller" in characters though. you measure it in complexity, statements, branches and so on. naming a variable `x` isn't better than naming it `loggedInUser`, even if it's shorter for the same reason that obscure bitwise operations to swap two variables aren't than using a temp variable, even if it's shorter. what matters is cohesion and readability. the code should mirror the actual logical process (on the appropriate level of abstraction). this LEADS to short methods/classes, but it's the cohesion and SoC you want, not the shortness.

Comment: @kai `x` vs. `loggedInUser` is an apples/oranges comparison to `result += add` vs. `result = result + add`.  there is no doubt the latter expressions are the same operation whereas who knows what you're defining as `x` and `loggedInUser`. i never said i measured "smaller" in characters...i said i measured "clean code" in writing the same expression more concisely.

Comment: @kai i agree with you on cohesion and readability. if i write code, i would like a fellow programmer to look at my code and understand it. if s/he doesn't, then i didn't do a good job writing my code.